# How can I obtain vector from data.frame

Tags: r

input

```
side <- c("ABC DEF", "XYZ", "GHF")
```

output

```
[1] "ABC DEF" "XYZ"       "GHF"
```

Now that I am importing data from excel, it is appearing as following using the given code:

```
library("xlsx2dfs")
Mydata <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx",sheet =1, rows=1:4)

                Name
1            ABC DEF
2                XYZ
3                GHF
```

How do i have the same output while importing from excel file. Also I want to delete headers whereby there are no headers in the file. Please help

Comment: `Mydata$Name`??

Comment: doesn't read.xlsx have a header argument which you can set to false?

Comment: Per `?read.xlsx`: colNames  If TRUE, the first row of data will be used as column names. It defaults to TRUE, though. So `Mydata <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx",sheet =1, rows=1:4, colNames=FALSE)` does the trick there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all and most important I think is that when you write "I used to make dataframe using the following code" you have to know it's not true - this way you are not creating `data.frame` object, but vector of values. You can think - maybe you know this - of `data.frame` as of table consists of rows and columns. And you can think of columns as a vectors - each column is a vector. Knowing this, you can ask: "how can I obtain vector from data.frame" and this is what @user2974951 showed in the comment - syntax is `my_data_frame$my_column` or `my_data_frame[["my_column"]]`.